# Issue with boolean modifier with self intersecting array

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to intersect an object (let's say a cube) with an array of some other object (let's say spheres). This works well as long as the objects of the array are disjoint. But as soon as these objects intersect, the original object disappears. Why does this happen, and what can I do to prevent it?

I show the mentioned toy example below. In my actual problem I use the array modifier to shift and rotate some object that will self intersect with the other copies, and I'd like to still be able to edit the original object from which the copies are made.

[image]

To recreate this problem:

- Create a shere in addition to the default cube, and make it smaller and shift it to the top surface of the cube.
- Add an array-modifier to the sphere such that multiple copies woudl intersect the cube.
- Add a boolean-modifier to the cube with the "difference" mode selected, and use the sphere as a target object.
- Hide the sphere such that you can see the hollowed out parts on the cube.
- Increase/Decrease the offset in the array modifier until the spheres intersect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the "self" box in the boolean modifier. This solved it for me.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's a pity the "self" parameter doesn't have a better name: according to the [docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html) it is there for exactly this situation.

Comment: Yes, if you hover above it, it shows a description of what it does.